# A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value

Tags: angular

In my angular2 app, I have service which send a get request to a url.

Here is my service:

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Gallery} from './gallery';

@Injectable()
export class InstagramService{

    constructor(private _http:Http){

    }

    getGallery(username: string) : Observable<Gallery> {
        var result=this._http.get("https://www.instagram.com/"+username+"/media/").map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

I have defined the return type as `Observable<Gallery>`, but it complains that:

```
A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value
```

What is going wrong with this code?

Comment: Since this was already necro'd by another edit, I'm rolling it back to the original form. Looks like OP edited the question to include the correct answer, which just makes the question confusing and invalid.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you declare a return type, then why not return anything?

Usually this is what you want in this case.

```
getGallery(username: string) : Observable<Gallery> {
     return this._http.get("https://www.instagram.com/"+username+"/media/").map(res => res.json());
}
```

`var result` probably doesn't what you expect anyway because `_http.get(...)` returns an `Observable` not a value.

The caller of `getGallery()` can then subscribe to get notified when the value arrives.

```
instagramService.getGallery.subscribe((result) => this.galleryData = result);
```

When a value arrives then `(result) => this.galleryData = result` is called and the `result` is assigned to `galleryData` of your current component or service.

Comment: if I specify return type as ```void``` why should I return something?

Comment: actually if you specify return type as void you're telling that won't return anything, I guess