# How to use MergeMap in Angular 11 / ionic 6?

Tags: android, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am very new with the MergeMap method to combine multiple API requests. I have following and reading this tutorial how to do it.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/handle-multiple-api-requests-in-angular-using-mergemap-and-forkjoin-to-avoid-nested-subscriptions-a20fb5040d0c

This is my code to get data from an API:

**Service.ts**

```
getPriceList(): Observable<Price[]> {    
    this.http.get<Price[]>(this.baseUrl).pipe(     
      map( priceId => {
        const id = priceId[0];
        this.priceId = id.id;
        return id;
            }),
     mergeMap( Id=> this.http.get(this.baseUrl2 + /${Id.id})),
      
    ).subscribe( productPrices => {
       this.productPrices = productPrices;
    });
  }
```

I need all the data from the first `baseUrl`, but I assign the Id to use it in my second api request. I call this method in **home.ts** like this:

```
 this.dataService.getPriceList().subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.priceListData = response;
```

There is no error when I call this method in the file.

The error is in the method from **Service.ts**

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return
> a value.ts(2355)

I am using the **return** statement in the first api request.

I have tried this solution:

[A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837261/a-function-whose-declared-type-is-neither-void-nor-any-must-return-a-value)

Then I get the following error:

> Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type
> 'Observable<Crypto[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6
> more.ts(2740)

How to use the MergeMap the right way in Angular 11 / ionic 6?

Comment: The last error seems unrelated to the posted code…?

Comment: The errors shows when I use `return this.http.get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should return something on getPriceList, which you weren't, and if you subscribe inside getPriceList there is no observable anymore to subscribe after that

```
  getPriceList(): Observable<Price[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<Price[]>(this.baseUrl)
      .pipe(
        map(priceId => {
          const id = priceId[0];
          this.priceId = id.id;
          return id;
        }),
        mergeMap(id => this.http.get(`this.baseUrl2${id.id}`))
      )
  }
```

and the call

```
this.dataService.getPriceList().subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
  this.priceListData = response;  
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank for your time. I have try your solution and I get the following error: 
 `Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Price[]>'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Price[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2322)`

Do I have to change the datatype?

Comment: i think it might be the type from the second get, so maybe this.http.get<Price[]>(`this.baseUrl2${id.id}`)) if that doesn't work change the types to any to make it run then is just a mather of finding the correct types

Comment: the first one return a price and the second one also return a price? what does each api call return?

Comment: The first one returns a json like this `[{id, name, price, priceId]` the second like this `{
    "prices": [ [16, 19],]
`

Comment: just change to Observable<any> for now. The first one is indeed a price and the second one is something else different

Comment: I have used your solution `this.http.get<Price[]>` and I get no error. When I start the app I see this in my chrome dev tools: 

`ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`

Comment: I am guessing this is on an  ngFor, the types might not be what you expect, comment any ngfors you might have. Does the   console.log(response);
 prints anything on the console?

Comment: I have fixed the ngFor type thank you so much for your time!